# Can I answer my own question if it accomplishes the goal, but does not answer the question directly?

Tags: discussion

Earlier today I [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384647/unable-to-get-from-multiprocessing-queue) that has yet to be satisfactorily answered, but I found an alternative solution. In the interest of future readers, would it be appropriate to answer my question using the workaround as it accomplishes the overall goal or should I simply let it be since I can't answer the specific issue I posted about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key here is that it *doesn't matter that you posted the question*. Would your alternative be a valid, useful answer if someone *else* had posted the question?

More than likely, you can and should post your solution. Just make sure that you actually answered the question you posed (which could be, "Its impossible! This works though...").

Answer (score 2):

An answer is "an answer" , meaning it is not necessarily the "whole" solution.

So yes, feel free to post it !

I would add, perhaps emphasize how it may only partially solve. And show what the missing piece is, etc.