# Submit an Answer which does not offer a solution to the exact scenario but solves the problem nevertheless?

Tags: discussion, answers, link-only-answers

I spotted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384702/custom-uiview-from-xib-not-appearing-in-uiscrollview) question. The user was programmatically loading a `UIView` in `iOS` and adding it to another element named `UIScrollView` and his problem was that the view's nib file was not loading or displaying. Since this was horrible re-invention of wheel (As iOS already provides us similar functionality via `UITableView`), I suggested that he should use `UITableView` instead of adding subviews with a loop inside a scrollview. This obviously provided him with the results that he wanted but it does not quite answer to his real question. I did not post my suggested approach as an answer for this reason and also because it was true only on his case but for other people facing a similar problem it won't be helpful. I did however gave him a link to correct way of loading a View's nib file (Already answered on SO) in comments. Should I have posted that as an answer? [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278843/can-i-answer-my-own-question-if-it-accomplishes-the-goal-but-does-not-answer-th) Meta discussion doesn't quite provide me a solid answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many questions asking "how do I do X" when "X" is a poor approach. Occasionally the asker really wants to know about "X". But, more commonly, I believe, the asker wants to solve a problem and thought that "X" was the best method to use. Perhaps this is a version of the [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Reading the linked question (which is about a topic I do not know) it seems the asker thought that "X" was the way to go, but they tried your recommendation and were satisfied with that approach.

I would say that you have provided a good answer to the askers problem and that you should write it up as an answer.

Comment: If another person comes to visit this question, they would be looking for the way to load the view correctly which most likely will not involve using the approach I suggested. I probably should add the link to the already question answer in this regard along with the alternative approach to tackle his specific issue.